# Clean URLs with Next.js using graphql-yoga

Tags: express, graphql, next.js, clean-urls

I would very much appreciate some help with implementing server side support for clean urls for next.js.

I'm using graphql-yoga (and prisma) on backend and next.js with apollo client on frontend.

My graphql-yoga server is running on the port 4444.

Not sure how to get it working and what would be the best approach.

I tried using [next.js documentation for server side support for clean urls](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls).

It uses server.get, which doesn't seem to work with yoga-graphql.

I also tried implementing [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes) as a middleware, didn't manage to make it work neither (seems that server.get never gets triggered).

Some answers that I found suggest having a separate file for next.js routes using a custom express server and a separate file for graphql-yoga.

I'm not sure how to run both server.js and index.js at the same time and if it is something that is advised to do.

In my backend/src/index.js:

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const createServer = require("./createServer");

const server = createServer();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {

   server.express.get('/item/:id', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/item'
      const queryParams = { id: req.params.id }
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
    })

    server.express.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

server.start(
  {
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, process.env.BACKEND_URL, process.env.PLAYGROUND_URL]
    }
  },
  deets => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on port http://localhost:${deets.port}`);
  }
);

})
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

I expect this code to provide clean urls for paths like:

localhost/item?id=1 (initial path)

localhost/item/1 (clean url)

However, when I navigate to localhost/item/1 from my frontend, I get a 404 error (the rest of the application working as expected) and when I start my graphql server, it keeps on logging in console: "Client pings, but there's no entry for page: /_error".

localhost/4444 gives a 404 error as well instead of showing graphql playground.